# RSpec 2.6, "Expected response to be a redirect to </bar/foo> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/bar/foo>."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rspec2

I wonder why *all* my redirection tests suddenly fail. All failures are of the sort mentioned in the subject. Normally this is an issue of mixing `foo_url`and `foo_path` in controllers and/or tests, but this isn't the case here.

The controller actions all look like

```
redirect_to :action => :foo
```

and the tests all look like

```
response.should redirect_to(:action => :foo)
```

and still I get errors like

```
Expected response to be a redirect to </bar/foo> 
but was a redirect to <http://test.host/bar/foo>.
```

Even when I replace `:action => :foo` with `foo_path` (or the equivalent named route) the error occurs.

Any ideas what might cause this to happen?

Comment: Did you try `redirect_to foo_path`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

Buried deep inside another test was this:

```
BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
```

to prevent (slow) reverse DNS lookups for tests which queried online databases. This, however, was a *global* setting and this caused the above error. Removing the `Socket.do...` made all redirection tests pass again. (BasicSocket had no such problem.)

I'm documenting this here so that others can find a solution faster.